# Cannot control Nvidia Shield volume while streaming to TV

Tags: volume-control, streaming, smart-tv, nvidia-shield

My setup:

- Nvidia Shield is connected to the TV
- I use the optical out of the TV to connect two speakers
- I use the Nvidia Shield remote to control the Shield volume out (not the TV volume or the speaker volume: just the Shield volume)

This setup has worked just fine for years, but I recently changed my TV from an old Panasonic plasma TV to a QLED from LG and it doesn't work anymore.

What happens is that I can change the volume just fine if I'm in the dashboard or if I play a file locally. But if I stream something (I tried Netflix, HBO Max, and Disney+), the volume doesn't change and I get the pop-up saying that I have to go into settings and set up the remote control. This ONLY happens when streaming, and it did not happen with my old TV.

I can change the volume just fine if I set the output to be the TV speakers instead of the optical out, but obviously that's not what I want. I have tried checking/unchecking IR, CEC, and HDMI fixed volume control in the Shield's settings but no luck. I also try to set up the remote again but also there, no luck.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to be able to make it work also during streaming. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was due to the new TV reporting being able to do surround.

The old TV did not do this, but what happens now is that because this one allegedly supports "surround", Shield expects that the remote for the surround system has to be used.

The workaround was to disable surround in the sound settings of Shield, and now the remote works just as before.

Still, it'd have been helpful to have a better message than "set up your remote", used in pretty much every kind of situation.